# Terminal check remaining battery health

Tags: battery, acpi

I've tried the following command

```
cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/info
```

And there it is

```
No such file or directory
```

`acpi` outputing this:

```
Battery 0: Unknown, 100%
```

Is there another way to check the battery's health?

Comment: gnome-power-statistics ?

Comment: Please provide: Ubuntu Version, Desktop Environment, Computer make and model. These will make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/info
```

or

```
cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/stat
```